# SQL Server 2008 R2 Db on SharedDrive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my local machine. Is it possible to create a database on a shared drive (network drive) so that all my teammates should be able to read data from the SQL Server database?

When I try to create a new database, it shows only my `C:` drive and not the network drive.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to place the database files on a network drive in order for your teammates to use the database.  You can host the instance locally and have your teammates connect to your instance.  Just enable TCP/IP using the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: SQL Server is a server based database. You don't connect to the file you connect to the service. Check out what is in a connections string. There's no filename in there, only a servername etc.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server takes out exclusive locks on the database files, thus you wouldn't be able to "share" it in real time with other teammates if they are trying to mount the database as well.

What you need to do is setup an environment for SQL Server and give your teammates access to connect to that instance of SQL Server. Do not attempt to use multiple instances of SQL Server with a single database (unless it is copied from a gold database build to each client).

Comment: Thanks every1 for ur suggestions. :)